# Передача id поста из ListView в другую активити

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, android-intent

Есть ListView в котором через REST загружается краткое описание постов. При клике на элементе списка вызывается второе активити, которое запрашивает у сервера расширенные данные по публикации и выводит их пользователю.

С самой передачей параметра post_id разобрался. В ListView повесил на элементы списка обработчик:

```
lv_posts.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, PostDetails.class);
        intent.putExtra("post_id", "61509");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Во втором активити получаю данные так:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
post_id = intent.getStringExtra("post_id");
```

Вопрос в том, **как post_id из первого запроса** (список постов) **привязать к элементам ListView** и **как потом их вытащить из нужного элемента и передать в putExtra** (вместо значения "61509" должно быть post_id конкретного поста).

Comment: Где post_id укажите имя текущего класса, а где "61509" укажите position. И в классе где получаете интент post_id будет равен кликнутой позиции, и получив номер позиции передайте его серверу, который по номеру позиции сверит с публикацией и выведет соответствующую

Comment: @McDaggen вопрос в том, как в качестве номеров позиций у ListView задать post_id, которые приходят с сервера?

Comment: попробуйте `setTag()` для каждого итема

Comment: @DmitryMaslennikov Создайте массив который будет заполняться из сервера, а затем создайте адаптер listView и в него передайте этот массив

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал не перегружать приложение большим количеством активити, и делать всё на фрагментах (просто подменять фрагменты в зависимости от реакции пользователя).

Этот вариант будет лучше со всех сторон :)

Также, лучше не использовать list view, который уже устарел на данный момент, а использовать Recycler View.

Теперь к самому вопросу: из него было не очень понятно, что и как нужно сделать, но примерную логику я уловил. Должна быть какая-то лента в приложении, и при нажатии на посты должна быть какая-то реакция, верно? Чтобы не передавать интент и не стартовать новое активити, можно просто поверх добавлять нужный фрагмент.

Я думаю, что нет нужды как-то напрямую привязывать к вьюшкам пост_айди, можно просто брать их из адаптера. Есть адаптер, берем из него элементы, устанавливаем нужную инфу уже на элементы списка, верно? Тогда можно брать пост_айди из адаптера по позиции. Или я что-то не так понял?

---

Берём RecyclerView из android support libraries, у него, как и у лист вью, есть адаптер, в адаптере есть метод onBindViewHolder, куда передается вью холдер (который у лист вью необязателен) и позиция элемента. В этом же адаптере есть ваш список, который формируете как хотите (из того же жсон), и в итоге из него дергаете элементы по позиции и устанавливаете текст/картинки и прочее уже основываясь на этом. Второй параметр у этого метода (onBindViewHolder) - позиция, вот по ней можно также дергать из списка элементы в любом другом методе адаптера. И у этих элементов списка могут храниться и другие нужные вам данные, в том числе всякие айди.